# Tools/utility to migrate mainframe db2 data into aws rds-postgres

Tags: amazon-s3, database-migration, amazon-rds

Can you please let me know the tools/document which I can use/refer to migrate data residing on mainframe `db2` system to `aws rds` (postgres).

Example - 
I have a table DB2 Employee with columns Id as Integer and Name as Char (30) with 100 records so how do migrate/convert DDL into postgres format and load data into postgres table.

I just browse through 'AWS Database Migration Service' but I don't see it support to migrate source db2 data to target aws rds or do we need to upload data on s3 and then load to rds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge AWS's Data Migration Service does not currently offer migration from a DB2 source RDBMS platform.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.html